# Get attribute value of hidden form element

Tags: javascript, html, postman, cheerio

I´m using Postman to automate some tests.
I need to get the value of the value attribute on the hidden field with the name "execution":

```
<form class="app-form" method="post" id="fm1" action="login" _lpchecked="1">
    <input type="hidden" name="execution" value="633ffc0f">
</form>
```

In postman, there´s only cheerio available for this.
I´ve tried variations of the following, but none is working:

```
$('input#execution').attr("value");
$('input[name=execution]').attr("value");
$('input[type=hidden]').attr("value");
$(':hidden#execution').attr("value");
$('input:hidden[name=execution]').attr("value");
```

Many thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`input[name=execution]` does work fine for me

```js
console.log($('input[type=hidden]').attr("value"));
console.log($('input[type=hidden]').val());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form class="app-form" method="post" id="fm1" action="login" _lpchecked="1">
    <input type="hidden" name="execution" value="633ffc0f">
</form>
```

Comment: Turns out my postman was going crazy, after restarting it worked again. :-o

Answer (score 3):

This is how you get value

```
const executionValue = $('input[name="execution"]').val();
console.log(executionValue);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/chille1987/3dap9yk4/2/

Comment: Thanks. Jsfiddle looks awesome, didn´t know it.

Answer (score 3):

Using your example HTML snippet, you *could* use this basic code in the `Tests` tab to save that value to an environment variable in Postman:

```
const $ = cheerio.load(pm.response.text());

pm.environment.set("hiddenValue", $('input[name="execution"]').val());
```

[image: Postman]

Answer (score 2):

use this to access value

```
$('input[name="execution"]').val();
```