# get element value from HTML response using Postman

Tags: javascript, postman, cheerio

Somewhere in the HTML response there is an element:

```
<input name="__RequestVerificationToken" type="hidden" value="I_NEED_THIS" />
```

How can I get it's value using Postman?

This is my code but I'm not happy with what it returns

```
const $ = cheerio.load(pm.response.text());
console.log($("title").text()); // get title to check if it works
console.log($("__RequestVerificationToken").attr('value')); //returns undefined
console.log($("__RequestVerificationToken").text()); //returns null
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get attribute value of hidden form element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57141913/get-attribute-value-of-hidden-form-element)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`"__RequestVerificationToken"` is not a valid selector since it is a name attribute you're looking for.

Instead, use the valid CSS selector like this:

```
const $ = cheerio.load(pm.response.text()).;
console.log($("input[name='__RequestVerificationToken']").attr('value'));
console.log($("input[name='__RequestVerificationToken']").text());
```